# WPF - The same effect on many elements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, effects

I have 64 labels with text.
How can I apply this effect to all of them except one?

```
<BlurEffect Radius="8.0" KernelType="Box"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <BlurEffect Radius="8.0" KernelType="Box"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Update**

For the Label that should't have this effect you can use

```
<Label Style="{x:Null}" ...>
```

or any other style that you may use

Comment: How can I apply this effect to all of them except one

Answer (score 1):

Put a style in your window resources which sets the Blur effect

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
             <BlurEffect Radius="8.0" KernelType="Box"/> 
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```